# GKE (autopilot) node outbound ip range

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine, mongodb-atlas, cidr

Long story short: Connecting to mongo atlas, and trying to whitelist the smallest ip range possible.

VPC peering won't work as the Mongo cluster is hosted in AWS, and it's just a Mongo Atlas limitation. Also, some of our mongo clusters are M5 (or lower), and they don't support VPC Peering.

That being said, I'm not sure what the public/external ip of my pods will be, when they attempt to connect to Mongo. If not narrowing the outbound ip range as much as possible, what other options exist.

The GKE cluster is not private, and it's autopilot

Comment: Any chance you can move to a private Autopilot cluster?

Comment: Your question is not specific, the connectivity between aws and gcp can be established in different ways, using public IP, VPN , how do you want to connect to Mongo from GCP ? If public, pods traffic will be SNAT to node IP, it will use the nodes external IP addresses which you can get using "kubectl get node -o wide", if gke is private and Cloud NAT is enabled, it will use CloudNAT IP , you can reserve static IP on CloudNAT and only whitelist those IP in the AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found these two articles that shows how you can route egress traffic to a single IP that can be used for whitelisting your GKE from Mongo Atlas:

[Route the GKE cluster's egress traffic via Cloud NAT](https://rajathithanrajasekar.medium.com/google-cloud-public-gke-clusters-egress-traffic-via-cloud-nat-for-ip-whitelisting-7fdc5656284a)

or

[Route your Public GKE cluster’s egress traffic via NAT instances](https://rajathithanrajasekar.medium.com/google-cloud-public-gke-cluster-egress-traffic-via-static-ip-addresses-for-ip-whitelisting-1cb024228e7e)

Unfortunately, both of these options only work for Non Autopilot GKEs. For routing the GKE cluster's egress traffic via Cloud NAT, the desired networking behavior is currently not supported by public Autopilot GKE clusters. The cluster's IP masquerade configuration is not configured to perform SNAT within the cluster for packets sent from Pods to the internet. Currently, there isn't a way to configure the IP masquerade agent to not masquerade the pod range when reaching out to the internet in Autopilot clusters. As a result, pod egress traffic in public Autopilot GKE clusters will be using the node's external IP.

So to move forward with Cloud NAT it's either:

- use a private GKE cluster, which can be in Autopilot mode.
- use a public GKE cluster, but not in Autopilot mode.

Comment: Thanks, had to change my cluster to be private... unfortunately, that's an immutable property, so had to recreate it

Answer (score 1):

Using Autopilot, you cannot use an inexpansive solution that is using [kube-ip](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeip) which will allow you to associate public GCP static ips to your GKE nodes. It is a daemon that runs in your kubernetes cluster and keeps checking and associating if necessary GCP ips that you bought earlier to your GKE nodes.

With Autopilot, what you can do is to use the Network Endpoint Group (NEG) abstraction layer that enables container-native load balancing. It allows to configure path-based or host-based routing to their your backend pods. The ingress is free, but you will pay for GCP loadbalancing which is much more expansive that reserving a few ips with kube-ip in most cases.

Here are [more informations about GCP's NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs). Plus another [related stackexchange question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1092539/assigning-different-external-ip-for-each-pod-on-gke-autopilot).